# I want to remove conda's env name

Tags: conda, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use oh-my-zsh with spaceship theme

Here, I want to remove conda environment's name which is (base)

[image: img]

In the image there's a (base) and also base. I'd like to delete first one.

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment by @merv provides an efficient answer. See [the documentation on `changeps1`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#change-command-prompt).

```
conda config --set changeps1 false
```

---

*Original answer, which is inferior to the answer above.*

If you want to remove the `(base)` prefix but keep the `base` environment activated, you can set the `env_prompt` configuration key:

```
conda config --set env_prompt ""
```

The default value for `env_prompt` is `'({default_env}) '`. See the [conda configuration documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=env_prompt).

Comment: wouldn't setting `changeps1` to false be more efficient? i.e., so it doesn't execute the PS1 change in the first place

Comment: @merv - yes i agree. thanks. i updated my answer.